# Multi core theora encoding

Tags: ubuntu, ogg-theora

We convert uploaded video to MP4 and OGV, but while trying to speed up the process we've hit a wall. We found the bottleneck is the OGV encoding, While it might take 5 minutes to convert a 350mb AVI to MP4, it takes roughly 25-30 minutes to convert the same file to OGV.

avconv supports multithreading/multiple cores but it seems that libtheora doesn't, does anyone have any way of encoding over multiple cores? I found an [old mail group](http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/theora-dev/2007-October/003365.html) which discussed a patch but I can't find much else about it, or if it even still works 5 years on.

So. Is multi-core theora processing possible and what should I use to do it?

For Reference:

```
avconv -y -i big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.avi -vcodec libtheora -qscale 10 -bufsize 20M -same_quant -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k buck.ogv
```

Comment: Have you tried `-threads 4` to see if libtheora supports threads?

Comment: Yes, it just processed as usual on 1 core of 4 available. I'm pretty certain it's not available as standard

Comment: Then build yourself a version with this patch from your link, and use that version.

Comment: The patch itself isn't linked in there, only a very old beta version of libtheora

Comment: OK, use http://svn.xiph.org/branches/theora-multithread/

Comment: Is this the only way of doing it, are there any other options?

Comment: What other options? You can just choose a different codec if you want. I don't think there are other libtheora encoders. See my answer, you can try the link to ffmpeg2theora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a link to a multi-threaded version provided in the [official site of libtheora](http://wiki.xiph.org/TheoraEncoders):

> theora-multithread: old, no longer developed, experimental encoder
>   library based on the old encoder, optimized for SMP/multi core
>   systems: [theora-multithread svn](http://svn.xiph.org/branches/theora-multithread/). For more info sees all the thread
>   here: [Multi-Thread Theora Encoder](http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/theora-dev/2007-October/003365.html).

Build that version, then try building ffmpeg using it. If newer versions of ffmpeg don't build with it, try older versions of the code.

There is also a multithreaded  version of [ffmpeg2theora](https://launchpad.net/ffmpeg2theora/+milestone/0.16-multithread).